# wordpress is_front_page() is not working (static front page)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a WP - Alert plugin for a wordpress website. The issue is that it displays on all the pages even though it is set as display on home page only. (is_home). However, my home page is a static home page so I have set it to is_front_page and still it displays on all the pages. If you could just let me know if I am missing out anything??

```
function wp_alert_add_sticky_alert(){
if(get_option('alert_show_on_site') == 'yes'){
    $display    = true;
    $homeOption = get_option('alert_show_on_home');
    $pageOption = get_option('alert_show_on_page');
    $postOption = get_option('alert_show_on_post');

    $getID = get_the_ID();

    if($homeOption == 'yes' && is_home ()){
      $display =  true ;
    }elseif($pageOption == 'yes' && is_page()){
      $display =  true ;
    }elseif($postOption == 'yes' && is_single()){
      $display =  true ;
    }else{
      $display =  false ;
    }
    if($display){
?>
<div class="sticky-box">
<div class="sticky-inner"><?php echo stripslashes(get_option('wp_alert_message')); ?>    
</div>
</div>
<?php
  }
}
}
?>
```

I added this line to the code above and still it won't display on the static home page only.
    } elseif($homeOption == 'yes' && is_front_page()){
          $display = true ; }

Thanks in advance guys :)

Answer (score 2):

WordPress loads `functions.php` before the `$wp_query` object has been set up with the current page.  `is_front_page` is a wrapper around around `$wp_query->is_front_page()`, and if the query hasn't been set up, it's always going to return false.

For more on the topic, see this question : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41805/is-front-page-only-works-in-theme-file-and-does-not-work-in-functions-php

To use it in your `functions.php`, you will have to wrap it in an action that is after the $wp_query object is instantiated.

```
add_action('wp', function () {
    if (!is_front_page()) {
        add_action('wp_print_styles', function () {
            wp_deregister_style('wpos-slick-style');
            wp_deregister_style('wpsisac-public-style');
        }, 100);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this showing in your static home page now??

Try this

```
function wp_alert_add_sticky_alert(){
if(get_option('alert_show_on_site') == 'yes'){
    $homeOption = get_option('alert_show_on_home');
    $getID = get_the_ID();
    if($homeOption == 'yes' && is_home ()){
   ?>
<div class="sticky-box">
<div class="sticky-inner"><?php echo stripslashes(get_option('wp_alert_message')); ?>    
</div>
</div>
<?php
  }
}
}
?>
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: Hi Wanderer, Thanks I did tried that before opening a thread here and it didn't work. Also tried if($homeOption == 'yes' && is_home || is_front_page()) { $display = true ; } and that didn't work either.

Comment: any help guys please? very much stuck here.. just needed it to be displayed on the static home page.

Comment: Hi Wanderer, thanks for your help. The function is fine and it displays on the static home page but it also displays on all the pages on the website. Just needed it to be on the static home page only. Have also tried the function with Wordpress conditional tag which is 'is_front_page' and when I use it then it doesn't display the alert on the website at all. Hope we are not missing anything here :)